# VMware Workstation 12 on Linux host - Transport (VMDB) error -45: Failed to connect to peer process

Tags: linux, command-line, vmware-workstation, debian-jessie

I installed VMware Workstation on Debian 8.2 with

```
./VMware-Workstation-Full-12.1.0-3272444.x86_64.bundle
```

and

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

installation without errors.

I installed Workstation on a Windows client to manage the VMS remote.

***I'm able to create and delete on the Debian machine, but not to start a VM!***

I get the following error message:

```
Transport (VMDB) error -45: Failed to connect to peer process.
```

Have anybody an idea?

thats the result **/var/log/vmware/hostd.log** try to power on a vm

```
2016-01-12T10:02:26.137+01:00 info hostd[7F58E1090700] [Originator@6876 sub=Libs] VigorTransportClientProcessError: Remote connection failure
2016-01-12T10:02:26.137+01:00 info hostd[7F58E1090700] [Originator@6876 sub=vm:/vmware/W73/W73.vmx]  VMX exited: '0 /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx: error while loading shared libraries: libXcursor.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2016-01-12T10:02:26.137+01:00 info hostd[7F58E1090700] [Originator@6876 sub=Libs] '
2016-01-12T10:02:26.139+01:00 verbose hostd[7F58E1090700] [Originator@6876 sub=Vigor.Vmsvc.vm:/vmware/W73/W73.vmx] Vigor client state callback 0 error Transport (VMDB) error -45: Failed to connect to peer process.
2016-01-12T10:02:26.139+01:00 verbose hostd[7F58E1090700] [Originator@6876 sub=Vigor.Vmsvc.vm:/vmware/W73/W73.vmx] Start Vmx message: Transport (VMDB) error -45: Failed to connect to peer process.
2016-01-12T10:02:26.139+01:00 verbose hostd[7F58E07A2700] [Originator@6876 sub=Vigor.Vmsvc.vm:/vmware/W73/W73.vmx] Power On message: Transport (VMDB) error -45: Failed to connect to peer process.
2016-01-12T10:02:26.139+01:00 warning hostd[7F58E07A2700] [Originator@6876 sub=Vmsvc.vm:/vmware/W73/W73.vmx] Failed operation
2016-01-12T10:02:26.139+01:00 info hostd[7F58E07A2700] [Originator@6876 sub=Default] StuffEvent: fullFormat resource ID = event.VmFailedToPowerOnEvent.fullFormat
2016-01-12T10:02:26.140+01:00 verbose hostd[7F58E07A2700] [Originator@6876 sub=PropertyProvider] RecordOp ASSIGN: latestEvent, ha-eventmgr. Applied change to temp map.
2016-01-12T10:02:26.140+01:00 info hostd[7F58E07A2700] [Originator@6876 sub=Vimsvc.ha-eventmgr] Event 6 : Cannot power on W73 on debian82.host.local in ha-datacenter. A general system error occurred:
```

**But the libfile exists:**

```
10:09 debian82.host.local:~# find / | grep libXcursor.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libXcursor.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libXcursor.so.1/libXcursor.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/lib/lib/libXcursor.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/lib/lib/libXcursor.so.1/libXcursor.so.1
```

**vmware-ui-5368.log from Windows Operation System**

```
2016-01-12T13:36:28.871+01:00| vmui| W115: Transport (VMDB) error -45: Failed to connect to peer process.
2016-01-12T13:36:28.871+01:00| vmui| I125: DlgUI: Transport (VMDB) error -45: Failed to connect to peer process.
2016-01-12T13:36:28.871+01:00| vmui| I125: VMPowerVIM::OnPowerChangeFailure -- 1 : false/Transport (VMDB) error -45: Failed to connect to peer process.
```

**That are the processes currently running at the host**

```
13:44 root@deb82:~# ps aux | grep vm
root       297  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   09:25   0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clean]
root       547  0.0  0.0  12860  3076 ?        Ss   09:25   0:01 /usr/bin/vmware-usbarbitrator
root       811  0.0  0.0 250092   516 ?        Ssl  09:25   0:00 /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmblock-fuse -o subtype=vmware-vmblock,default_permissions,allow_other /var/run/vmblock-fuse
root       873  0.0  0.0   6848  1584 ?        Ss   09:25   0:00 /usr/bin/vmnet-bridge -s 6 -d /var/run/vmnet-bridge-0.pid -n 0
root       954  0.0  0.0   6820   188 ?        Ss   09:25   0:00 /usr/bin/vmnet-netifup -s 6 -d /var/run/vmnet-netifup-vmnet1.pid /dev/vmnet1 vmnet1
root       961  0.0  0.0  16980  5628 ?        Ss   09:25   0:00 /usr/bin/vmnet-dhcpd -s 6 -cf /etc/vmware/vmnet1/dhcpd/dhcpd.conf -lf /etc/vmware/vmnet1/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases -pf /var/run/vmnet-dhcpd-vmnet1.pid vmnet1
root       964  0.0  0.0   9696  2624 ?        S    09:25   0:00 /usr/bin/vmnet-natd -s 6 -m /etc/vmware/vmnet8/nat.mac -c /etc/vmware/vmnet8/nat/nat.conf
root       966  0.0  0.0   6820   192 ?        Ss   09:25   0:00 /usr/bin/vmnet-netifup -s 6 -d /var/run/vmnet-netifup-vmnet8.pid /dev/vmnet8 vmnet8
root       973  0.0  0.0  16980  5624 ?        Ss   09:25   0:00 /usr/bin/vmnet-dhcpd -s 6 -cf /etc/vmware/vmnet8/dhcpd/dhcpd.conf -lf /etc/vmware/vmnet8/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases -pf /var/run/vmnet-dhcpd-vmnet8.pid vmnet8
root       987  0.0  0.0  20812   476 ?        Ss   09:25   0:01 /usr/sbin/vmware-authdlauncher
root      1241  0.0  0.5 1483760 88384 ?       Sl   09:25   0:13 /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-hostd -a /etc/vmware/hostd/config.xml
```

**What i tried to exclude that the problem is a remote windows session:**

started xming and enabled x11 forward with ssh session. thats the way i installed,managed vms in a previously test environment. but i'm not able to start the managementtool direct from the shell with the command: vmware (it seems it need a while after a few seconds it won't bring up the gui and fall back to shell)

**MY SOLUTION for that major problem:**

***I installed the host operation system again with minimal requirements and with systemtools (debian jessie 8.2)
After vmware workstation installation i'm able to connect, create and START any vms.
I don't know whats the problem was before!
Thank all for the SUPPORT***

Comment: There are several references to problems similar to yours on Google. have you tried any of the proposed solutions? If so, where did they fail? What error messages did they produce? In other words:what have you tried?

Comment: thanks for your answer. it was a fresh installation of debian. before i installed vmware on my system, i did a testing enviroment with the same hardware. all works great. after i had test enoth i decide to make a fresh clean install of debian. i tryed all what i could found in the world wide web :'(

Comment: Try to power on a VM, and after it fails, take a look at the UI log (its location is given in the Help > About dialog).  It sounds like the UI either is failing to launch the vmware-vmx process or is failing to connect to it. (When you try to power on a VM, is a vmware-vmx process started?)

Comment: **SOLUTION**: Please scroll down to the end of my question area.

Comment: If you have a solution, you may answer your own question. Adding answers to the question is not acceptable.